# What could be the best way to return a message if my method return an array in c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, file, io

I'm developing an application and I'm creating a method that has to read a file, but I'm not sure how to return a message in case that the file doesn't exist because my method return an array

Here is what I have:

```
MyFile = "C:\\MyFile.txt";

private string[] LoadFile()
{
    string Lines[];
    if (! File.Exist(MyFile))
         //????? <- return a message here!!
    else
       Lines = File.ReadAllLines(MyFile);
    return Lines;
}
```

I was thinking to do this, is the best way to do it?

```
private string[] LoadFile()
{
    string Lines[];
    if (! File.Exist(MyFile))
    {
       Lines[] = new string[1];
       Lines[0] = "File Not Exist";
    }
    else
       Lines = File.ReadAllLines(MyFile);
    return Lines;
}
```

Then catch the error message and print it?

What is the best way to that validation?

Comment: you can print the message and return an empty array or null.

Comment: Your options are probably to return `null`, an empty array, or throw an exception. An exception would probably be the most in-line with file functions throughout the framework.

Comment: Are you only allowed to return an array ???

Comment: As a note, your second example is not bracketed to match the indention. *Always* using curly braces with `if` statements is an advisable practice. Another note is that it is quite possible for your file to exist for the check, but not exist when you actually try to read from it, in which case you'd get an exception anyways.

Comment: LoadFile would only read lines in an array, that file will contains data that will be used in other existing methods.

Answer (score 13):

Most of the given answers are not great.  The right solution is:

```
private string[] LoadFile()
{
  return File.ReadAllLines(MyFile);
}
```

End of story.  If the operation fails it will throw, and the thrown exception will tell the caller why it failed.

Why do you not want to check for file existence yourself? Because (1) what if the file exists when you check, and then is deleted before you try to read it?  That is a rare case but it is possible, so you'll have to write the exception handling code anyways. If you're going to have to write the exception handling code either way then why do the check at all?  And (2) what is so special about the file not existing?  You are not checking for any other possible error condition, like: the file exists but someone else has locked it, the file exists but you don't have permission to read it, the file exists but it is on a network drive and the network cable got unplugged halfway through reading the file, and so on.  Are you going to write code to check for all these conditions?  How are you going to write code that detects a network cable being unplugged *in the future*?

Use exceptions to detect and handle exceptional situations. That's what they're for. Don't write any of that logic yourself; the framework developers already wrote it for you. Use their work, don't reinvent it badly.

Answer (score 3):

Throw an exception of a suitable type. 
Then catch the exception in the calling code and perform whatever exception handling is appropriate (such as displaying an error message).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are a few approaches that I could recommend for you:

1. As others have stated, throwing an exception is an acceptable way to pass additional information, such as an error that the file does not exist, to the calling method.  The disadvantage is of course that now you must remember to catch your exception, otherwise your application crashes and burns.

   ```
   throw new Exception("Your error message here");
   ```
2. If your requirement is simply to return the string array or else indicate somehow that an error has occurred, consider returning `null` to indicate that the operation could not complete.

   ```
   private Result LoadFile() 
   {
       if (!File.Exists(MyFile))
       {
           return null;
       }
       ...
   }
   ```

3. You can encapsulate your array with a class that has two fields, one for the array, and one for a value such as an enumeration or string providing the additional information you need back.

   ```
   enum States 
   {
       Success,
       FileNotFound,
       ...
   }

   class Result
   {
       public string[] Lines { get; set; }
       public States State { get; set; }
   }

   private Result LoadFile() 
   {
       // You code here
       ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can throw some custom exception:

```
private string[] LoadFile()
{
    string Lines[];
    if (! File.Exist(MyFile))
       throw new Exception("File doesn't exists")
    else
      Lines = File.ReadAllLines(MyFile);
    return Lines;
}
```

And then when you calling this method you can try/catch it:

```
try
{
    // call your LoadFile() method
}
catch (Excetion ex)
{
    // return some user-friendly message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon what you will do next. If the user of the program is selecting that file (which is not found) then instead of throwing an exception you should return this And you should return a object with two properties.

```
public class LoadFileResult
{
     public IEnumerable<String> Lines {get; set;}
     public bool FileNotFound {get;set;}
}
```

And then return your

```
private LoadFileResult LoadFile() { .... }
```

btw you can make LoadFileResult as a private nested class as well because LoadFile method itself is a private method so any returned value obviously will be used within that class.

Last thing, throw exceptions only when you encounter something which you are not expecting. If you know that there is a possibility that file won't be there then what's the point of throwing and and catching that exception.

Answer (score -1):

Throwing an exception is the most common approach in propagating errors up the call stack. But if you are asking about returning multiple values (of different actual or logical types eg. number of lines in the file and an array of non-empty lines) from a function use `out` parameters https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways to do what you want. You can send back null array result and check it in calling program or pass one out parameter to method to get error or throw custom exception. Below is sample implementation.

```
string MyFile = "C:\\MyFile.txt";

//Option 1 - use out parameter to send error back to calling program
private string[] LoadFile(out string error)
{
    error="";
    string[] Lines;
    if (! File.Exist(MyFile))
         error="File Not Found !" <- return a message here!!
    else
       Lines = File.ReadAllLines(MyFile);
     return Lines;
}

//Option 2 - throw custom exception
private string[] LoadFile()
{
    error="";
    string[] Lines;
    if (! File.Exist(MyFile))
        throw new ApplicationException("File Not Found");
    else
       Lines = File.ReadAllLines(MyFile);
     return Lines;
}
```